# Active Admin: pass instance variable for custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, activeadmin

I have a custom page in ActiveAdmin called statistics, where I want to display charts with data from the database.

Now I used the [Gon gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast) and want to pass the data to my custom page through an instance variable.

Usually you would add the gon line to the index action

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    gon.rabl "app/views/products/index.json.rabl", as: "products"
  end
end
```

But there is no controller in active admin for my custom page. How should I do this?
Or do I have to do this through the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your custom page being rendered from a 'Resource' controller ie from a resource that you have created in you application? If yes, then that is a controller itself. You can defined any custom action in the controller for the same. 
And you can use the same strategy to pass data to your page as you do for partials ie by using the :locals

Answer (score 10):

There is controller in active admin, despite this you can not pass instance variable to arbre part. But you can use `params` hash for this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'SomePage' do
  menu :label => 'Menu label'

  controller do
    def index
      params[:some_var] = 'value_of_some_var'
    end
  end

  content 'Page title' do
    h2 "This is some_var: #{params[:some_var]}"
  end
end
```

P.S.: If you don't want to change `params`, then all instance variables are stored in `@arbre_context.assigns`. You may also do like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'SomePage' do
  menu :label => 'Menu label'

  controller do
    def index
      @some_var = 'value_of_some_var'
    end
  end

  content 'Page title' do
    h2 "This is some_var: #{@arbre_context.assigns[:some_var]}"
  end
end
```